# Modeling Absolute Difference in Outcome

Tags: modeling, panel-data

I have searched far and wide but wasn't able to come up with an answer, even though it strikes me that this should be a common problem.

I am examining the inclusion of a specific type of clause in corporate contracts and its dependence on a corporation's general counsel. In other words, I am interested in whether usage rates of those clauses are driven by the GC. My outcome $Y_t$ is the mean frequency of that clause, averaged over all contracts for a given company in a given year and my variable of interest $X_t$ is an indicator variable for whether the general counsel is the old one or the new one - there has been only one change in general counsel in the relevant period.

So ultimately, I have panel data where an intervention occurs once per unit and treatment is permanent (i.e. if the intervention occurred in period 4, then $i$ is treated in 4, 5, 6 ...). I am not interested in whether the intervention has a positive or negative effect on the units, but in whether there is any effect at all.

Formally, I guess estimating the following model would give me the effect I am interested in:

$$|\Delta Y_{t,t-1}| = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_t$$

where

$$|\Delta Y_{t,t-1}|=|Y_t - Y_{t-1}|$$

Now an additional complexity (that is a secondary concern at this moment) is that my outcome is a fraction, i.e. $Y \in [0,1]$. So if $Y_{t-1} = 1$, the change can only be negative or zero.

I am at a complete loss on how to estimate such a model. Since the outcome is always positive, OLS seems to not be a good choice. But the structure of the outcome variable also doesn't seem to fit Tobit models or count data models.

It would be of great help if anyone has an idea on how to estimate such a model or if you could point me to the relevant literature. I can't seem to find anything that is helpful.

Comment: What does your variables represent??

Comment: I don't know how detailed I should be but I am examining the inclusion of a specific type of clause in corporate contracts and its dependence on a corporation's general counsel (i.e. are usage rates of those clauses driven by the GC). $Y_t$ is the mean frequency of that clause, averaged over all contracts for a given company in a given year and $X_t$ is an indicator variable for whether the general counsel is the old one or the new one - there has been only one change in general counsel in the relevant period.

Comment: Could you please add this information as an edit to the post?  As much context as possible in question helps getting (better) answers!

Comment: Done! Sorry about that.

Comment: Since you know the number of contacts with the language and the totals, you could consider logistic regression instead. How will you tell whether this is just a matter of a new law / changes in how everyone writes contractors due to something (i.e. under GC these sentences would have become more common from year X onwards)?

Comment: Do you mean logistic regression where my outcome is the inclusion of the clause or logistic regression where my outcome is the absolute change? If the latter, I am not sure about the number of contracts, e.g. if the fraction changed from $Y_t = \frac{10}{20}$ to $Y_{t+1} = \frac{15}{50}$. It is my understanding that the model I am trying to estimate rules out the possibility that changes in language would be driven by things other than my intervention (change in GC). But I can also always run placebo tests on companies that have not changed their general counsel over the period of observation.